# PHP sessions AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, сессия

Есть файл index.php
`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['privilege'])) {
    $privilege = $_SESSION['privilege'];
}
require_once ('classes/user.php');
$user = new User();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>users.loc</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Пользователи</h1>


            <div id="menu">

                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu-list">
                        <?php if (!isset($privilege)): ?>
                        <li class="menu-list-item"><a id="toregistration" href="#">Регистрация</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-list-item"><a id="tologin" href="#">Авторизация</a></li>
                        <?php
else: ?>
                        <li class="menu-list-item"><a id="toprofile" href="#">Мой профиль</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-list-item"><a id="toall" href="#">Пользователи</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-list-item"><a id="exit" href="#">Выход</a></li>
                        <?php
endif; ?>

                    </ul>
                </nav>


            </div>

        </header>

           <div id="content">

            </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

`

Через AJAX подключаю файл profile.php
`

```
$('#toprofile').click(function() {
        var jqxhr = $.get("../includes/profile.php", {
        })

            .done(function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
            });

    });`
```

Сам файл profile.php

```
 <div id="register" class="animate form">
                <h2> Профиль </h2>
                <div>
                    <img id="profile_photo" src="../img/img.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                <p> 
                    Логин: <?php echo $_SESSION['login'] ?>
                </p>
                <p> 
                    ФИО: <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>
                </p>
                    <p class="signin button"> 
                    <input id ="register_button" type="submit" value="Изменить имя"/> 
                </p>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Проблема в том, что файл profile.php не видит сессию, а при попытке session_start() выводит ошибку Cannot start session when headers already sent. Переменные сессии устанавливаются в другом файле и спокойно вызываются в index.php

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете стартовать сессию, если уже был какой-то вывод на экран. Будь то php-код или сообщение об ошибке - неважно.

Из вопроса не видно, где именно вы пытались стартовать сессию, но причина, скорее всего, в этом. Вам в сообщении об ошибке пишут - headers already sent. А заголовки посылаются только тогда, когда начат вывод на экран.

Для подключения сессии в profile.php начало файла должно выглядеть так

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div id="register" class="animate form">
```

Comment: Сессию запускаю сразу в index.php, до отправки заголовков. То есть мне из подключаемых файлов нельзя обратиться к сессионным переменным?

Comment: При чем тут index.php, если вы из ajax стартуете profile.php? У вас при ajax  ничего другого не исполняется

Comment: Вот в этом и вопрос, могу каким то образом к сессии обратиться из profile?

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?> прямо первой строкой в этом файле. Дополнил ответ

Comment: Тогда у меня выводит Cannot start session when headers already sent

Comment: Я объяснил, почему вылазит. Где-то идёт вывод до этого. Этот вывод должен быть виден в том, что возвращает ajax